# variable in a command using echo

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

I'm quiet new to scripting and I struggle a bit with this command, maybe someone can help

When I use this command, everything's works

```
titi=`echo 'scale=6; 10/65535' | bc -l | awk '{printf "%.6f\n", $0}'
echo "titi = $titi "
```

And I get this

```
titi = 0.000152
```

Perfect

But when I try to use a variable in it, I got an error:

```
toto=10
titi=`echo 'scale=6; $toto/65535' | bc -l | awk '{printf "%.6f\n", $0}'` 
echo "titi = $titi "
```

Result

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

So it's obvious the way I write the variable in the command is wrong, but I don't know how to write it

Can someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes to expand variables and note that [`$()` is
recommended over backticks in command
substitution](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/sc2006).  It
should be:

```
$ toto=10
$ titi=$(echo "scale=6; $toto/65535" | bc -l | awk '{printf "%.6f\n", $0}')
$ echo "titi = $titi "
titi = 0.000152
```

(notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command).